# Passing the event argument to a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following directive

```
.directive('uiBlur', function() {
return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
        elem.bind('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(attrs.uiBlur);
    });
};
```

})

This is the HTML

```
<input id="mainOdd1Id" type="number" ng-model="data.mainOdd1" placeholder="#1 Main Odd" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" min="0" step="any" ui-Blur="testfn('data.mainOdd1', $event, '#1 Main Odd');">
```

And this is the function in the controller

```
$scope.testfn = function(propertyName, $event, placeHolder){
    alert(propertyName);
}
```

I see in the debugger that $event is undefined...

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Try this ,  ng-click="myfunc('data.mainOdd1', { $event: $event} ,'#1 Main Odd')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is broken in more than one place.

1. Attrs are always string. So you cannot pass them to scope.$apply which expects function.
2. You need to parse expression runing it with $parse service.
3. You need to use event argument passed to event listener.

Here is working example:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('uiBlur', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('blur', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $parse(attrs.uiBlur)(scope, {
            $event: event
          });
        });
      });
    };
  })
  .controller('Example', function($scope) {
    $scope.testfn = function(propertyName, $event) {
      console.log(propertyName, $event);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example">
  <input type="text" placeholder="#1 Main Odd" ui-blur="testfn('data.mainOdd1', $event, '#1 Main Odd');">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. A few things, what is $parse output? I see you pass to the function (scope, $event), and get (propertyName, $event), is that correct?

Comment: @A.S.FStudio checkout documentation for $parse https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse There are examples there and quite a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind uiBlur with event received in the directive

```
.directive('uiBlur', function() {
return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
        elem.bind('blur', function(evt) {
        scope.$apply(attrs.uiBlur.bind(evt);
    });
};
```

You might also need to bind properties like data.mainOdd1 and #1 Main Odd